# How to create .model files while doing model transformation using ETL

Tags: eclipse, epsilon

I am doing a model transformation using Epsilon Transformation Language. I already have the meta models for the input and output models. I have written the transformation code and want to check if it works for a small hello-world application.So, I wrote a JUnit test.

I have a hello-world application written according to my input meta-model, and I also have the hello-world application that I am expecting from my transformation. However, in this link, http://www.eclipse.org/epsilon/cinema/
they have shown .model files for the input and output models. I have no clue as to how I can obtain .model files from my hello-world files. The file extension of my hello-world applications conform to their respective meta-model, for eg. hello-world.xml.

Please can someone tell me how to generate the .model files from any other file format?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Could someone please help me out :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who might face this issue in future, here is the solution, that I figured out myself. A .model file is basically an xml file. If in eclipse, you see it without using exceed editor, you can see the xml structure. If you try to manually create a dummy .model file and check the xml structure, you will understand how to make your own model files from the code of your  hello world. Basically, you can write an application in java that extracts the necessary information from the code and generates an xml file.

Comment: Spot on. In practice EMF models (which are probably the most common models people work with) can have any extension and, as you found out, the important part is that the contents follow the XMI format. Note that it is XMI not XML, and important but subtle difference. However, EMF must know about your extension in order to correctly load the models into memory and persist them later. ".xmi" is the default EMF extension and ".model" is provided by Epsilon. If you want to use another one you would need to register it with EMF.